# What are the differences between "-" and "--" in commands?

Tags: command-line

I often see a single dash `-` or double dash `--` followed by linux commands or other installed linux programs.

**What are the differences between single dash and double dashes?**

Is it just about abbreviation?  For example, `-v` means `--verbose` most of the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between - (one hyphen) and -- (two hyphens) in a command?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/813303/whats-the-difference-between-one-hyphen-and-two-hyphens-in-a-command)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a matter of convention. POSIX standard programs usually only have single character options, and they're all prefixed with a single hyphen. The longer versions are a GNU improvement for clarity, as far as I can tell, and usually are prefixed with double hyphens. You can see this in the libraries and programs used to parse options - `getopt` and `gnu-getopt` respectively. Non-GNU and non-POSIX-compliant programs may do something else altogether. Note that you really can't be sure that the long form of an argument may be the same from program to program. `-f` usually means `--force`, but not with `apt-get install` (common misconception). `-v` may mean version - usually, or `--verbose`, and so on. Check the man pages or other documentation to be sure. Also have a look at the [Wikipedia article on getopt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt). All this predates Linux by a decade or more.

`dd` is an example of [a POSIX standard utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) which doesn't have any hyphenated options *at all*. `find` is the classic example of [a POSIX standard utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47) that has word options with single hyphens - nearly all of `find`'s options are multiple characters long. [`ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ps.1.html) supports multiple option styles:

```
This version of ps accepts several kinds of options:

1   UNIX options, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a dash.
2   BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used with a dash.
3   GNU long options, which are preceded by two dashes.
```

[GNU `tar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Styles.html#SEC35) also supports multiple option styles.

As a matter of usage, prefer the long options in scripts if you can be sure that the scripts will be run in compatible environments - the improvement in clarity is a blessing when debugging. For portability, the short options are preferred.

Answer (score 6):

Usually - options can be chained together, like `pacman -Syu` being equivalent to `pacman -S -y -u`, and -- options generally take a parameter as in `./configure --prefix=/usr`