# What's the difference between - (one hyphen) and -- (two hyphens) in a command?

Tags: command-line, bash

Both seem to be flags but what is the difference?

Comment: There are two answers with very different interpretations. The reason for this is because `-` and `--` have two very different roles in two very different contexts. In the answer by @Rinzwind below, the context is  command line argument flags, and it's really just by *convention*. This is a convention followed by many (but not all!) programs in Unix-like environments. The answer by @heemayl describes the roles that `-` and `--` play in Bash syntax. Although you've accepted an answer, it would be helpful to clarify the question to know which context you mean.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- `--` is the long name version
- `-` is the short name version

Have a look at `man ls` and some of the options:

```
-a, --all : do not ignore entries starting with .
-A, --almost-all : do not list implied . and ..
-b, --escape : print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters
-B, --ignore-backups : do not list implied entries ending with ~
```

They are the same but some prefer the short, some the long versions.

And both are there for compatibility. Removing an option breaks software.

---

Not every command follows this this. As @ Bakuriu mentions in comment: a command like `find` has what you can consider "long names" with 1 hyphen.

---

In regards to coding there is something to note too:

- Bash's [getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) does not support long names.
- The [getopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) from the GNU utils does.

Comment: I believe you should also mention that not all programs follow this convention. For example `find` uses only the single hyphen version even for specifying long options, and other programs too.

Comment: But then those commands dont use long options but short options ;-) Them options being long-text still makes them short :D

Comment: You should also note that short options can be (usually/often) merged, so "-abc" is not equal to "--abc", but often to "-a -b -c". This is not of course true for programs that use  single dash multiletter options (e.g. openssl)

Answer (score 35):

Generally:

- `-` means to read the argument/content from STDIN (file descriptor 0)
- `--` means end of command options, everything follows that are arguments

**Why needed:**

About `-`:

```
$ echo foobar | cat -
foobar
```

Although `cat` can read content from STDIN without needing the `-`, many commands need that and their `man` pages mention that explicitly.

Now about  `--`, I have created a file `-spam`, let's `cat` the file:

```
$ echo foobar >-spam  

$ cat -spam         
cat: invalid option -- 'p'
Try 'cat --help' for more information.

$ cat -- -spam      
foobar
```

Without `--`, `cat` takes `s`, `p`, `a`, `m` all as it's options as they follow `-`, `--` explicitly indicates the end of option(s), after that `-spam` is taken as a file name.

Comment: Oh that is true too :D I assumed he meant the `--` and `-` in front of options :D

Comment: you can also use `cat ./-spam`

Comment: Apparently, these are just arguments, the behavior of which most likely depends on the command that uses them.

Comment: And how do parameters differ from arguments in this context (`--`)?

Answer (score 8):

This actually depends on the program concerned. There are standards, but they aren't actually *enforced* anywhere: it's up to each program to implement them.

The `find` command, for example, takes full name parameters with single hyphens:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -delete
```

However, in general, double hyphens indicate a switch which is a full word, and single hyphens indicate a swich which is a single letter. And single-letter switches can be combined, which means that all of the following commands are equivalent:

```
cp --verbose --recursive /dir/from /dir/to
cp -v -r /dir/from /dir/to
cp -vr /dir/from /dir/to
```

A double hyphen followed by a space can also be used to indicate "this is the end of commands; everything that follows is a file name, even if it looks like a command".

And a single hyphen with no following letters can indicate "read from stdin, not from a file".

However, *all of this is program-dependent*. Any given program can violate any of these standards, as seen, for example, with `find`.

Comment: The correct answer.

Comment: +1. Maybe not even a standard, but more of a loosely held, preferred convention.

Comment: Parts of it really are standard. Not the `--option`, which is a GNUism, but the parsing of `-vr` as equivalent to `-v -r` (when `-v` is an option that does not accept an option-argument) is enshrined in [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), and thus obligatory for compliant implementations of POSIX-specified tools.

Answer (score 4):

One hyphen is the way *options* to a command traditionally has been given to Unix-commands.  They have one hypen followed by a single letter (or sometimes number) (`-a` `-i` `-T`).  Some options are followed by an argument (`-ofilename` `-o filename`).

Two hyphen is mostly used - and is the prefered way of giving options - for programs/commands on GNU-systems - ie. mostly on Linux-systems.  They have two hypens followed by one or more words seperated by single hypens (`--version` `--ignore-case`).  Options with arguments uses an equal-sign to seperate option and argument (`--log-file=filename`)

The drawback with the old one-hypen options is that there are no standard letter to do the same thing over different commands.  Yes, `-v` is often used for "verbose" - and `-V` is sometimes used for "version" - but there is no real consesnsus between commands.  For example `-i` means "interactive" for `cp`, `mv`, `ln` and `rm` - the command will prompt before overwrite or delete.  But it menans "ignore case" in `grep`.  To make it even more difficult, the command `sort` uses `-f` - for "fold case" - in the same way, to ignore upper and lower case.  To make the confusion complete, many commands - including `mv` and `cp` - uses `-f` for "force"... that the command *must* do something (like overwrite an existing file), even though it usually wouldn't.

On top of that, the commands for different Unix-systems (Solaris, *BSD, SysV, AIX, ...) may use different letters to do the same thing.  For example the `who` command lists the users on a system.  This command can optionally show which users accept messages from other users to their terminal - the option for this is `-w` under Linux, while Solaris uses `-T`.

Long options on the other hand, allows the same option to be used on all commands and they actually describe what the options does.  For example `--ignore-case`, `--interactive`, `--version`, `--force`.  Thus `--ignore-case` is used in both `grep` and `sort`.

But again, they are almost only used in commands/programs made as part of the GNU-project...

Finally a double hypen is used to tell a command that the list of options are finished, and that what follows are arguments - no matter how much they may *look* like options.  If a filename starts with an hyphen (eg. `-this_is_a_bad_filename`), commands may confuse it with an option and try to parse it - the double-hyphen prevent this.  `mv -vi -- -this_is_a_bad_filename this_is_a_better_filename` (only command you should use if a filename starts with a hyphen... ;-)